# Data type format changes when inserting data to another table (MICROSOFT SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Original Data

[image]

Command used:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please **DO NOT** post screenshots of your code and sample data - post the information right here in the question, properly formatted and ready to use for others trying to help you!

Comment: is the `result` that you posted correspond to the `Original Data` ?

Comment: Please post the DDL for both source and destination tables